# Refresh data in GridView after every Change in Data

Tags: java, android

I am receiving data from an API call. I am able to send that data to my GridView in MainActivity.java and update the gridview once after I have received the first version of the data but when I click on the grid, the data changes and I need the gridview to refresh and show the updated data, which is not happening. I am calling the same callback again, which I am doing at the start which gives me the first version of the data.

My APIManager.java class :

```
public class APIManager {

    DeviceCallback deviceCallback;
    private static final String TAG = "APIManager";
    private static final String API_URL = "https://base-url"
    private static final String AUTH_TOKEN = SplashScreen.getTOKEN();
    private static List<Device> deviceArray = null;
    public void setDeviceCallback(DeviceCallback deviceCallback) {
        this.deviceCallback = deviceCallback;
    }

    void toggleDeviceState(Context context, String deviceID) {
        String URL = "https://baseurl/" + deviceID;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // Process the JSON response
                        try {

                            parseToggleStateResponse(response);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle API call error
                        Log.e(TAG, "API error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "jwt " + AUTH_TOKEN);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    void fetchInitialData(Context context) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // Process the JSON response
                        try {
//
                            parseResponseData(response);
                            JSONArray ownDevices = response.getJSONArray("owndevices");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle API call error
                        Log.e(TAG, "API error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Jwt " + AUTH_TOKEN);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    ToggleResponse parseToggleStateResponse(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {


        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JSONObject device = response.getJSONObject("data");


        Device deviceData = gson.fromJson(device.toString(), Device.class);
        Log.w("API-MANAGER", "125 : Response = " + deviceData.getId());
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceArray.toArray().length; i++)
        {
            String deviceID = deviceArray.get(i).getId();

            if (deviceID == deviceData.getId()) {
                Log.w("API-MANAGER", "DEVICE FOUND : " + deviceArray.get(i).getGivenName());
                deviceArray.get(i).setState(deviceData.isState());
                deviceCallback.deviceCallbackFunction(deviceArray);
            }
        }

        ToggleResponse responseData = new ToggleResponse(deviceData, message);


        return responseData;
    }



    DeviceResponse parseResponseData(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {


        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JSONArray ownDevicesArray = response.getJSONArray("owndevices");

        Device ownDevices[] = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(ownDevicesArray), Device[].class);
;
        DeviceResponse responseData = new DeviceResponse(ownDevices);
        List<Device> ownDevice = new ArrayList<>();;
        List<Device> delDevice = new ArrayList<>();


        // Parse ownDevices
        for (int i = 0; i < ownDevicesArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject deviceObject = ownDevicesArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Device device = new Device();
            Log.w("API-MANAGER", "153" + deviceObject.getString("_id"));
            device.set_id(deviceObject.getString("_id"));
            device.setName(deviceObject.getString("name"));
            device.setGivenName(deviceObject.getString("givenName"));
            device.setState(deviceObject.getBoolean("state"));
            device.setAdmin(deviceObject.getString("admin"));
device.setDelegate(getStringListFromJSONArray(deviceObject.getJSONArray("delegate")));
            device.setSchedulerFlag(deviceObject.getBoolean("schedulerFlag"));
            device.setTopic(deviceObject.getString("topic"));

            device.setMultiState(deviceObject.optString("multiState"));


            ownDevice.add(device);
        }
        deviceArray = ownDevice;


        deviceCallback.deviceCallbackFunction(ownDevice);
     

        responseData.setOwndevices(ownDevice);
   

     
        return responseData;
    }

    private List<String> getStringListFromJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            list.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }
        return list;
    }



    public interface DeviceCallback {
        void deviceCallbackFunction(List<Device> deviceData);
    }
}
```

GridAdaptr.java :

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    private final List<Device> deviceData;
//    private final int [] images;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    APIManager apiManager = new APIManager();
    public GridAdapter(Context context, List<Device> deviceData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.deviceData = deviceData;
//        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return deviceData.toArray().length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
        holder.GivenName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.GivenName);
        holder.image= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.image.setImageResource(deviceData.get(position).isState()? R.drawable.switch_on : R.drawable.switch_off);

        holder.GivenName.setText(deviceData.get(position).getGivenName());




        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                apiManager.toggleDeviceState(context.getApplicationContext(), deviceData.get(position).getId());

                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+deviceData.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }



    public class Holder
    {
        TextView Name;
        TextView GivenName;
        TextView State;
        TextView MultiState;
        TextView ConnectFlag;
        ImageView image;

    }

}
```

My MainActivity.java :

```
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements APIManager.DeviceCallback {


    public static GridView gridView;
    private Boolean hasConnection = false;
    String token = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null);

        APIManager apiManager = new APIManager();
        SocketClass socketClass = new SocketClass();
        apiManager.setDeviceCallback(this);
        apiManager.fetchData(getApplicationContext());
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
         gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);


      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Log.w("API-MANAGER", "Item : " + item.toString());
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void deviceCallbackFunction(List<Device> deviceData) {


        GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, deviceData);
        Log.w("API-MANAGER", "49" + deviceData.get(0).getGivenName());

        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after refreshing the Grid! It

Comment: How do I refresh the grid? I tried calling the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but that didnt work.

Comment: If I understood well, the problem is that you are getting the data (confirm with the Log?) and filling the grid with it, but you do not see the data updated on grid? When I said "after refreshing the Grid" I meant after setting the adapter to the GridView. Please, try changing rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null); for rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, parent);